# Asus A15 FA506IC UBUNTU 18.04.6 wifi adapter not found

Tags: drivers, wireless, asus, mediatek

I am using ubuntu 18.04.6 Bionic Beaver and wifi adapter is not available.

03:00.0 Network controller: MEDIATEK Corp. Device 7961

```
Subsystem: AzureWave Device 4680
Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 255
Memory at ff20300000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [disabled] [size=1M]
Memory at ff20400000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [disabled] [size=16K]
Memory at ff20404000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [disabled] [size=4K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
```

Kernel version : 5.4.0-87-generic

Note: I want to use Ubuntu 18.04 only because the yocto build is working fine in this version.

Is there any way i can download and install the driver for mediatek?

Comment: You need a new kernel, 5.14 I guess.

Comment: Updated to 5.14.10-051410-generic but normal boot not working, then i went into 5.14 recovery mode and booted from there. so 5.14 is booting up but still no wifi

Answer (score 0):

Solution is Update ubuntu from 18.04 to 20.4 and change the kernel to 5.14 which mt7921 driver.

Follow the below post to update the kernel seamlessly.

https://www.linuxcapable.com/how-to-install-linux-kernel-5-14-on-ubuntu-20-04/